# How to add icon 57x57 in XCode 5

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode5

I am working with Xcode 5 and created 3 icons

- iphone-58.png
- iPhone-80.png
- iphone-120.png

When I created my projected I dragged and dropped these three icons into image.xcassets. see screenshot.

Now when I compile my project I get this error that 57x57 & 57x57@2x icons are missing. How do I add them? I don't see any spot in AppIcon section. What did I miss?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can choose the icon sets that are required. [image]

Notice on the right side there are options for the appicon sets. Choose whichever one you want to put.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, I can add/remove by clicking on those check boxes. Your answer is marked.

Comment: This solved my problem. It's just weird xCode doesn't show the placeholder for this appIcons even they are requried.

Answer (score 16):

Use Below steps

1 - Go to `Project Navigator`
2 - chose (click on) `Images.xcassets` File
3 - Click on `APPIcon`( Left Top Corner)
4 - Go to `Attributes Inspector`
5 - Chose what you want.

[image]

Simple.

Thanks
DamithH

Comment: this jus easiest way to add :) ty

Answer (score 7):

I had to do this the hack job way.

- Go to your project folder
- navigate to Images.xcassets
- navigate to AppIcon.appiconset
- edit Contents.json file
- add this

  {   "images" : [
          {
            "size" : "57x57",
            "idiom" : "iphone",
            "filename" : "iphone-57.png",
            "scale" : "1x"
          },
          {
            "size" : "57x57",
            "idiom" : "iphone",
            "filename" : "iphone-114.png",
            "scale" : "2x"
          },
          {
            "size" : "29x29",
            "idiom" : "iphone",
            "filename" : "iphone-58.png",
            "scale" : "2x"
          },
          {
            "size" : "40x40",
            "idiom" : "iphone",
            "filename" : "iphone-80.png",
            "scale" : "2x"
          },
          {
            "size" : "60x60",
            "idiom" : "iphone",
            "filename" : "iphone-120.png",
            "scale" : "2x"
          }   ],   "info" : {
          "version" : 1,
          "author" : "xcode"   } 
  }
- now copy your two icons and paste them in AppIcon.appiconset dir i.e. iphone-57.png & iphone-114.png

Either this is a xcode bug or apple has assumed none of the apps made in xcode 5 will ever run on iphone 4 or lower or ios 6 or there has to be an easier way

[image]

Comment: i have a logo png image 500dpi how to use it inImages.xcassets

Answer (score 2):

My designer uses [makeappicon.com](http://makeappicon.com/), so I get a neat `AppIcon.appiconset` dir that I just need to drag into `Images.xcassets`.

Using this service you can get Android cuts as well.

And it's free.

Comment: it takes less than 60 seconds to resize icons in photoshop. Also I don't trust other websites with my data. Who knows what they will do with it. If there was a stand alone program that I can install on my mac that would do the same resize then that is better.

Comment: @SamBudda, while I do appreciate your "hackerz in my data, stealing my iconz" concerns, I would like to point out that any hacker interested in your icon design is more likely to just grab it from the App Stroe.

Comment: Wow les then 60 seconds, why would I use a free instant service if I could just spend 15 minutes in photoshop which I don't really want to install on my laptop.

Also you can just resize using preview which is just as simple but doesn't require a massive application :).

Answer (score 1):

The right panel (where are the icons) is bigger than Xcode screen sometimes, but the panel doesn't have a scroll. Try to hide both Navigator and Utilities to have more room for the main content.

Comment: I did, I maxed out my screen and still there was nothing there. I had to do it the hack job way which I will post here