# Appicon comes up proper on iPhone 4S running on iOS7 but not on iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, iphone-5

Recently, I updated my Xcode to Xcode 5 for iOS7 development which brought up the assets catalog for simplifying the use of image assets. I have set the appicon for our app and it's coming up nice and sharp on iPhone 4s running iOS7 but on iPhone 5, the same appicon comes up blurred.

This is what I have in my assets catalog:

**Appicon**

**iPhone app iOS 5,6 57pt**

**1x** (Properties - Screenshot)

[image: under 1x]

**2x** (Properties - Screenshot)

[image: under 2x]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, from your screenshots, that your "`@2x.png`" file is 114 x 114... while the [Apple Human Interface Guidelines say that the icon should be "120 x 120"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html).

Answer (score 0):

For `appicon-1.png`, the size is marked as being `120 x 120 pixels` while underneath it says

> Idiom iPhone
>
> Size 52
>
> Scale 1x

It *should* be marked as being `120 x 120 pixels` (that part's correct) while underneath it says

> Idiom iPhone
>
> Size 60
>
> Scale 2x

Comment: Make an image file that's 60x60 instead of 57x57. You've made a mistake with the image file itself, it's not part of the Xcode settings.

Comment: and that would be set to 1x or 2x? 

Currently i am trying to set 2x to 120 px according to Michaels answer.

Comment: Just create a 120x120 image and slot it into the space marked `iPhone App iOS 7 60pt` in your image assets catalogue.

Comment: Then you're not using the images catalogue correctly and your life is all the worse off for it. Go to your app's settings and make sure the `Source` of your `App Icons` is part of the catalogue. Within the catalogue editor you can right-click and choose `New App Icon` if it's missing.

Answer (score 0):

this below has been very helpful to you. I had fixed same issue with referenced by this below links

[iPhone 5 App icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908019/how-to-add-icon-57x57-in-xcode-5)

Thanks... if you have clarification let me know